# ASPxGridview get row data from server-side

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm working on a DevExpress Gridview and I want to get the data of the selected row (only one row can be selected at the time). I'm working on the Server-Side and I'm using FocusedRowChanged function.

EDIT: The FocusedRowChanged fire but nothing happen and the textboxes do not change value

```
protected void dxgrDepartement_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "FetchData", "<script                          language='javascript'>FetchData('4654654646')</script>");
            txtDescription.Text = "patate";
            //txtComments.Text = dxgrDepartement.GetRowValues(dxgrDepartement.FocusedRowIndex, "IdDepartment").ToString();
        }
```

And the "FetchData :

```
        function FetchData(text) {
        //ClearField();
        document.getElementById("<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>").value = text.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW - Changing the callbacks property made no difference for us.  We needed callbacks for other functionality so couldn't turn this off anyway.

The GetRowValues method did not work either.

This is a technique described on DevExpress' web site and it worked for us as long as we didnt use DevExpress' controls (ASPxDateEdit, ASPxTextBox):

ASPX page:

```
    <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Dist. %" FieldName="DistributionPerc" VisibleIndex="3"
        Width="50px">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDistPerc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DistributionPercent") %>'
                Width="50px" />
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Code behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdHistory.VisibleRowCount; i++)
{
    TextBox textbox = grdHistory.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, grdHistory.Columns["DistributionPerc"] as GridViewDataColumn, "txtDistPerc") as TextBox;
    var anything = textbox.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
gridView.GetRowValues(gridView.FocusedRowIndex, columnFieldName1, columnFieldName2, ..., columnFieldNameN)
```

Method [ASPxGridView.GetRowValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowValuestopic)
Property [ASPxGridView.FocusedRowIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FocusedRowIndextopic)

Comment: Actually, it work only when the page load, it show me the value of the DefaultFocusedRow

Answer (score 1):

`grid.EnableCallback = false;` solved my problems!